# Tomar un dato de Combobox y pre-visulizar la seleccion

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy realizando un programa en Python Tkinter y necesito tomar el valor que selecciono en el Combobox y visualizarlo en un texto/titulo sin la necesidad de presionar un botón.

La idea seria, escoger una opción desde el listado del Combobox y que esta se muestre entre las comillas del texto.

De antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

caja = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['ENERO', 'FEBRERO', 'MARZO'])
caja.grid(row=1, column=1)

texto = Label(root, text=f"Mes pre-seleccionado '{caja.get()}'")
texto.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Programa Ejecutado]

Comment: Asumiendo que el usuario no puede escribir nada en el combobox, solo seleccionar una opcion, podrias usar el evento <<ComboboxSelected>>. Este evento se activa cuando seleccionas un item del combobox. Puedes enlazar una funcion a este evento haciendo elcombobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", unafuncion). El resto te lo dejo a vos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu principal problema es que al iniciar el script/app intentas obtener directamente un valor del Combobox cuando todavía no se ha seleccionado ningún campo de este. Por este mismo motivo te devuelve `"`.

Primero de todo `debes esperar a que se seleccione un campo y después obtener el valor seleccionado`.

**Para hacer esto tienes dos formas de hacerlo :**

Con un `botón` que al hacer click te devuelva el valor seleccionado.

Por ejemplo :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

def onClickButton():
    texto.config(text=f"Mes pre-seleccionado '{caja.get()}'")

caja = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['ENERO', 'FEBRERO', 'MARZO'])
caja.grid(row=1, column=1)

get = Button(root, text="Ver pre-seleccionado", command=onClickButton)
get.grid(row=3,column=1)
texto = Label(root, text="Mes pre-seleccionado :")
texto.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Lo que aquí hacemos es que al dar click al botón llamamos a la función `onClickButton` donde obtenemos el valor seleccionado del Combobox y configuramos la Label`texto` para añadir el valor de este.

---

La otra forma que tienes de hacer esto es utilizando la función `tuCombobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", EJECUTAR ALGO)`. Por ejemplo :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

caja = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['ENERO', 'FEBRERO', 'MARZO'])
caja.grid(row=1, column=1)
caja.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda _ : texto.config(text=f"Mes pre-seleccionado '{caja.get()}'"))

texto = Label(root, text="Mes pre-seleccionado :")
texto.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Lo que esta función hace es que al seleccionar un valor del Combobox (`"<<ComboboxSelected>>"`) ejecutamos `lambda _ : texto.config(text=f"Mes pre-seleccionado '{caja.get()}'")` para asignar el valor seleccionado a tu Label `texto` como hemos hecho anteriormente.

Comment: Llevo despierto 5 minutos... Cualquier duda o aclaración que necesites escribe un comentario!

Comment: Muchas gracias!, lo que si no entiendo muy bien la parte del " lambda _ : ". Que es lo que hace específicamente en el guion bajo. No conocía esa forma de utilizarlo.

Comment: @Naub en Python una función `lambda_:` es una función anónima (carece de nombre) en vez de definirse como `def():` se utiliza `lambda_:` seguido del código a ejecutar.